# How to implement this list with Android Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I've found a screenshot on the Google Documentation of the Material Design for Android and like to implement this style in my own app. The problem here is, that I have no idea which font sizes and gaps between the elements have to be implemented.

Does anyone has some source code for this example or any hints on the dimensions?

[image: Screen design from Google Documation]

Answer (score 0):

[Google design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) should help you out. I believe the following is relevant to your question:

- [Lists](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#)
- [Text fields](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#)
- [Metrics & keylines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#)

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547545/how-to-make-android-list-view-design-from-android-l-preview-design) was asked before, the `xml` code should give you an idea.